# Does チャンプルー come from Indonesian?

Tags: etymology

Quoted from [the Japanese Wikipedia entry about チャンプルー](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC)

> チャンプルーの語源は、インドネシア語・マレー語のcampur[1][2]（チャンプールまたはチャンポール：音声は[3]）との説がある[1]。この語は、同語源の日本語のちゃんぽんと同様「混ぜる」「混ぜたもの（料理）」という意味を持ち、インドネシア料理にはナシチャンプルという、飯と数種類のおかずを混ぜた料理がある（ナシ nasi はインドネシア語で飯の意）。

Does チャンプルー come from Indonesian?

Comment: Not helpful to answering this question in particular, but it wouldn't be the first time Japanese loaned other words for arguably native dishes. Even tempura is a loanword from portugese (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempura#Origins)

Comment: Hints: (1) Why is チャンプルー written in katakana?  (2): There has been exchange between Okinawa and Indonesia since 14th century.  (I trust that you know チャンプルー is an Okinawan word that has only been used actively about 20-30 years in the rest of the country.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about this word's (チャンプルー) history in Japanese, but yes, in Indonesian there is a word "campur". Campur means "mix"; from an Indonesian-Japanese dictionary: 混合、混ぜる、干渉する。 Because I often hear this word "campur" in Indonesian, in my opinion, it could have come from Indonesian.

Answer (score 1):

(From WWWJDICT)

> [CHANPURUU](http://tangorin.com/general/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC)
>   noun:
>   chanpuru; champuru; Okinawan stir-fry dish, usually containing vegetables (especially bitter melon), tofu, meat or fish (poss. from Indonesian "campur" meaning mixed)